# Is there a way to affect a familiar with a spell that targets animals?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

Basically what i had in mind was a way to target a familiar with [Anthropomorphic animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/anthropomorphic-animal) so that he can manipulate tools and speak, but since a familiar becomes a magical beast, it shouldn't be posible.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: The only way I know is first turning your familiar into an animal with Polymorph and then use Anthropomorphic animal on it. But that seems kinda silly and pointless.

Comment: @LouisHuppenbauer While the relevant rules, admittedly, could do to be a lot clearer and more explicit, Polymorph by itself does not change the subject's creature type. I think there might be some ways to get around this, though; certainly, the psionic equivalent (the Metamorphosis line) does have some ways, via class abilities and the like, to get them to change creature type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is cast the spell on your own familiar. Familiars, from master level 1, have an ability that has you covered:

> Share Spells: The wizard may cast a spell with a target of “You” on his familiar (as a touch spell) instead of on himself. A wizard may cast spells on his familiar *even if the spells do not normally affect creatures of the familiar's type* (magical beast).

Emphasis mine. This clause is usually used to allow buffs to work on familiars that usually only work on humanoids, but it works just as well with buffs that usually only work on animals. Note that you can save a spell level and accomplish similar results with the Alter Self spell, though that one won't allow it to speak a language unless it has one to use, so if planning to do that version with any regularity, you'll want a thrush or raven as the base familiar.

Comment: -1: That line doesn't use super clear language, but I'm fairly certain that it's only there to let you use self-targeted spells that don't work on animals on your familiar.  It seems sort of weird to be able to ignore all creature type requirements for all spells on your familiar, whether you're using your Share Spells ability or not.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl The language is VERY clear. What it was intended for is not, but the wording absolutely does not even slightly support your position. They had *every possible chance* to say "even if the spells normally only affect animals", but instead they made *no mention at all* of the animal type, and said "even if the spells do not normally affect creatures of the familiar's type". This is not merely fairly clear, it is a fantastic degree of clarity of wording which is rarely to be found in RPG books.

Comment: Since when is Anthropomorphic Animal (a target of animal touched) a spell with a target of "you"?  You, the PC, cannot target yourself with this spell because you're not an animal.  Pathfinder definition of animal _An animal is a living, **nonhuman creature**, usually a vertebrate with no magical abilities and no innate capacity for language or culture._

This is so you can cast spells such as Enlarge Person on your familiar.  You are a legal target for such a spell you cast yourself--therefor you can cast it on your familiar.  You are not a legal target for anything that targets "animal".

Comment: @claudekennilol **Read the ability I quoted.** It has two **separate** clauses. One allows spells with target "you" on the familiar, the other allows spells that don't target magical beasts. Neither one requires the other to also be applicable. If it did, the ability would be pretty much useless, since there are almost no spells with both a target of "you" *and* a creature type requirement.

Comment: Also, your own example (Enlarge Person) would, under your version, have the same problem as Anthropomorphic Creature, since it doesn't have a target of "you" either. The Share Spells ability says nothing about "being *able* to target yourself", it says it has "a target of "you"". The latter is a very specific reference to the way personal spells are defined by the game (range of "personal" and target of "you" are 1:1 correlated in the spell descriptions).

Comment: You're right in this, I was merely being too argumentative because you were wrong with the other statement about familiars being able to use tools and didn't think through what you posted well enough.